python to_excel return carriage in a header
In my Dataframe I have a column named "Prénom du collaborateur".
When using Pandas to_excel I get a wide column in Excel.
I would like to get the header on two lines; 
first line, "Prénom du" 
second line, "collaborateur"
I'm exporting the dataframe into Excel with the following code.
data = {'Nom du collaborateur': ['Robert Lewandowski']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

file_path = "output/OUTPUT_EXCEL_FILE.xlsx"
df.to_excel(file_path, index = False)

It works without error but inside the generated Excel file, the text is a single line. there is no carriage return.
I am trying to set the column name (Excel header) on two lines in order to reduce the width of the column.

You need to explicitly declare any carriage return in your column name (using '\n' special character)
import pandas as pd

data = {'Nom du\ncollaborateur': ['Robert Lewandowski']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

file_path = "output/OUTPUT_EXCEL_FILE.xlsx" 
df.to_excel(file_path, index = False)

Once in excel, the column header may not looks split on several lines but it is (just click on it, the display will update)

exactly ! by specifying \n. I open the excel file and then by clicking on "wrap the text" the header is diplayed on 2 lines
